# User Profile Replication Problems when Many Colleagues

Tags: user-profile, profile-sync, user-profile-service

We are using User Profile Replication Engine http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc663011.aspx to transfer information from old userprofile service to new userprofile service.

Anoyne else experiencing problems when replicating user profiles with large amount of users ex 60.000+ users? The problems seems to be occur when a profile has lots of colleagues which need to be replicated. For example this may take up to 17 minutes for user with 190 colleagues. Some users will also have more colleagues. This is 5 sec for each colleague. The replication therefore takes for ever and never completes. Any suggestions or people who have experienced the same?

Comment: 60,000+ users!! :)

Answer (score 1):

User Profile Synchronization takes a long time, especially with a lot of users and with a lot of information to sync.

Cumulative updates have improved the performance (IMHO quite a lot) over the last year. What CU ar you on?

Comment: We are on CU4 Dec 2010

Answer (score 0):

IS everyone everybody else's direct colleague then? I'd think everyone was at least divided into departments etc. A full import for us over 50000+ users takes 3 hours, but none of em have say for instance the manager property set in AD, they're all "single" users.

Comment: No not everyone are direct colleagues. But departments can get big like ~2000 people.